# Regarding Roam Research – Graph Overview (canvas, d3, react)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, canvas

Regarding Graph Overview page in Roam Research, I'd like to ask how those canvas tags are created.

Does anyone have a clue how those graphs inside canvas tags are created? with d3.js on canvas or some other ways?

If they are created with d3.js on canvas, could you recommend some articles or anything that I could have a look?

(I've been trying to create a project on react with a similar look with that...)

Here's a screenshot below – Roam Research Graph Overview

- Here, even though nodes are on canvas (The whole canvas page is zoomable, and I can drag them or click them)

[Roam Research Graph Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8FLv.png)